How does this delta-sigma modulator work without a clock signal
I've been recently studying about delta-sigma modulators trying to understand a schematic of an amplifier, while I came across this simulation of 2nd order D-S modulator, by far this is what I was able to understand from this image, correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. The first op amp with sine input acts as an error amplifier to subtract the feedback signal from 1 bit DAC (5th op amp), this output from input op amp is fed to an integrator to shape the noise.
My question is:

If I try to remove the 2nd integrator and connect the output of 3rd op amp and try to convert it to an first order modulator, it doesn't seem to work.
How is the self oscillating condition developed?

Link towards the simulation .

Use a better spice tool to investigate loop gain. The oscillation is rather apparent in the positive loop gain at 0 degrees of phase shift. Removing an integrator adds 90 degrees of phase margin probably, so oscillations will be suppresses.

Going all the way around the outer feedback loop, starting at the diff-amp at the left, the signal encounters:

The leftmost difference amp, with a gain of -1, which is a phase shift of 180°
An integrator (500 Ohms, 5nF), with a phase shift of 90°
The center difference amp, with a gain of +1, shifting by 0°
Another integrator (500 Ohms, 50nF), shifting by 90°
A comparator, essentially operating as an automatic gain control for the purpose of our analysis, with 0° phase shift

If we sum that up, we get 360° of phase shift and a variable gain of at least unity (constant amplitude at the comparator output). Barkhausen tells us that that should be an oscillator.
The additional negative feedback introduced at the center difference amplifier tweaks the loop response slightly to ensure a consistent, stable oscillation. You'd have to do a more in-depth analysis to figure out how exactly it affects operation.
And if you remove one of the integrators, there's just not enough phase shift for oscillation. The system will be more or less stable. (With real-world OpAmps and comparators, it'll likely oscillate at an awfully high and unusable frequency).

I have some doubts regarding this answer, 1) If i use a second order integrator, can i get an 180 degree phase shift? 2) how is the first difference amplifier or error amplifier providing an 180 degree phase shift, isn't it just an unity gain non-inverting op amp. Also i have been reading some Research papers and thesis on these topics, I'm getting somewhere slowly, can you also suggest some resources on how to model these systems and analyze them s-domain. Thank you for your response, i almost lost hope for replies.

@chethanRaj 1) Yes, and that's exactly what this circuit does, with an added feedforward input in the middle. A 2nd-order integrator is just two cascaded 1st-order ones, and that's what you see in this circuit. 2) No. It's a difference amplifier with a gain of 1. The signal going around the loop is subtracted, giving a gain of -1 (not +1). 3) I sadly don't know any good resources at the moment.

Hi Jonathan, can i remove the need for the difference amplifier( Error amplifier ) by connecting an coupling capacitor for the input signal and connect the feedback directly to the inverting terminal of the OP-AMP, i have been following this reference design from infineon at page 50, perhaps this isn't the first time you came across this schematic, you have also helped me previously over this topic, appreciate your help.

@chethanRaj No, you can't do that directly. What you can do is to invert the digital modulator output and then use a summing integrator, which is what the circuit you linked does. However, this isn't on-topic for this particular question anymore. If you want to ask an additional question, please open another one.
